# Auto Layout implementation in already developed app in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone

I have already developed an IOS app in Objective C, Xcode 6 in which I have disabled the auto layouts and size classes.

Is it now possible to use auto layout after having disabled it earlier?

If yes, how can I implement it? When I enable the auto layouts and size classes and I implement the constraint on the label, the background colour of the label changes to white. When I do this for other object types, they become invisible.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, **yes**: it is indeed possible to use Auto Layout in an app after having disabled it. Each Xcode project template just gives you an initial starting point – nothing is set in stone.

For the second question, the best way of implementing Auto Layout in an app is to just take it one view at a time. You don't need to go all-or-nothing with Auto Layout; it's possible to just use it in certain cases but use frame based layout in others. Start on smaller, easier views and go from there.

The last issue around background colors is a little trickier without having screenshots or code samples. I have had views disappear on me after implementing Auto Layout and the issue always boiled down to bad constraints. The best solution I can give there is to just do the usual view-debugging work (as in, printing frames and manually setting bright colors to see where views actually are) and figure out what is going wrong.

Having the background color change to white is interesting, though... Auto Layout should not be affecting that at all. It sounds like the background color got changed somehow while the constraints were being created.